# Split first element of object in html

Tags: angularjs, split

in my car object i have a value car.photos it's look like this:

car.photos :

```
15214615_01_hd.jpg|15214615_02_hd.jpg|15214615_03_hd.jpg|15214615_04_hd.jpg|15214615_05_hd.jpg|15214615_06_hd.jpg|
```

My question is:  Is it possible in my html with the ng-src display the first element of my `car.photos`?

***my html:***

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in $data">
                <td><img class="img-rounded resize" ng-src="../photos/15214615_01_hd.jpg"></td>
...
</tr>
```

Comment: if it is a string, then you got to convert it into an array first

Comment: @manasisakhare i can do that directly in my html code ?

Comment: no. You should do it in the Angular controller for the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call it as `getSrc()`

```
<img class="img-rounded resize" ng-src="{{ getSrc(car.photos) }}">
```

in controller,

```
$scope.getSrc = function (photos) {
    return  photos.split("|")[0];
}
```

Comment: it's not an array is a string with `|` separator

Comment: sorry there wasn't a type of the `car.photos` property in the question. updated the answer please check.